# Can an email ID be used as username in android app

Tags: android

I know this kind of question has been asked before, but there is a twist here. This username is for an Android game. Which will show top 100 players username on Facebook app. Is it OK to show email IDs of the top 100 users every month on a Facebook app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

showing email ids on public forum will cause you legal problems as you will violate user privacy. And your users will end up with loadz of spam :)

Instead you should show some user name. Most of the games we see shows only the user name not the email address or any other sensitive data.

I don't think showing emails would be a good idea.